# ColdFusion cached queries are cleared automatically

Tags: caching, coldfusion

I am using the **CachedWithin** attribute in **CFQUERY** to cache ordinary select queries. This is working fine, however, what I notice is that the cache seems not get refreshed at the specified intervals.

For example if I use **CachedWithin="#createTimeSpan(0,0,30,0)#"**, the query gets cached for 30 minutes, but then is cleared and not refreshed after that.

My understanding was that CachedWithin schedules to refresh the query at the interval specified by createTimeSpan. My ColdFusion Administrator is set to cache 500 queries and I am sure this is not due to a memory or storage issue.

Am I missing something here? Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: The data is kept around for 30 minutes from the last time it was used. It is not from 30 minutes from the first use. The idea behind cacheing queries, is that the most used ones should be kept around because they are the most used. Getting rid of something useful is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

What makes you think that the query would be *refreshed*? (Wishful thinking does not count.)

The attribute is called `cachedWithin`, not `refreshedAfter`.

---

If you want to do something every 30 minutes, use a scheduled task. Refreshing queries should probably not be it, though, as this happens automatically anyway when the first request comes in after a cached query has expired.